# Windows 10 - Cannot Move Window Partially Off-Screen

Tags: windows, snap

I am not sure how this might have happened, but I suddenly find that when I try to drag windows in Windows 10 so that they partially are off-screen, they refuse to stay there and snap back to be fully on-screen. Please note that this is *not* the default "snap" windows behavior (under multitasking) I have disabled that, and it still happens. It is also not behaving that way - even when the mouse cursor is not near the edge, it still happens.

Any help appreciated - everything I find online is about recovering from a window off-screen which is kind of the opposite of the behavior.

Thanks!

EDIT: As of today, the problem seems to have gone away...I rebooted several times before to try to resolve the issue. But overnight...its gone. Thanks for whomeever read this and thought about it. I have no idea what happened.

Comment: You didn't recently install any software by Stardock, did you? Or any other desktop customization software, like DisplayFusion?